# Join two table and count, avoid zero if record is not available in second table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have following tables products and tests.

```
select id,pname from products;                                                     
+----+---------+                                                                   
| id | pname   |                                                                   
+----+---------+                                                                   
|  1 | prd1    |                                                                   
|  2 | prd2    |                                                                   
|  3 | prd3    |                                                                   
|  4 | prd4    |                                                                   
+----+---------+                                                       

select pname,testrunid,testresult,time from tests;                       
+--------+-----------+------------+-------------+                                  
| pname  | testrunid | testresult | time        |                                  
+--------+-----------+------------+-------------+                                  
| prd1   |       800 | PASS       | 2017-10-02  |                                  
| prd1   |       801 | FAIL       | 2017-10-16  |                                  
| prd1   |       802 | PASS       | 2017-10-02  |                                  
| prd1   |       803 | NULL       | 2017-10-16  |                                  
| prd1   |       804 | PASS       | 2017-10-16  |                                  
| prd1   |       805 | PASS       | 2017-10-16  |                                  
| prd1   |       806 | PASS       | 2017-10-16  |                                  
+--------+-----------+------------+-------------+
```

I like to count test results for products and if there is no result available,for a product just show a zero for it. something like following table:

```
+--------+------------+-----------+----------------+---------------+               
| pname  | total_pass | total_fail| pass_lastweek  | fail_lastweek |               
+--------+------------+-----------+----------------+---------------+               
| prd1   |      5     |     1     |      3         |       1       |               
| prd2   |      0     |     0     |      0         |       0       |               
| prd3   |      0     |     0     |      0         |       0       |               
| prd4   |      0     |     0     |      0         |       0       |               
+--------+------------+-----------+----------------++--------------+
```

I have tried different queries like  following, which is just working for one product and is incomplete:

```
SELECT pname, count(*) as pass_lastweek FROM tests where testresult = 'PASS' AND time
>= '2017-10-11' and pname in (select pname from products) group by pname;       
+-------------+---------------+                                                 
| pname       | pass_lastweek |                                                 
+-------------+---------------+                                                 
| prd1        |          3    |                                                 
+-------------+---------------+
```

it looks so basic but still I am unable to write it, any idea?

Comment: Pname would not be a column in any sensibly designed test table. Beyond that, this is incredibly basic and would be thoroughly addressed in any basic, introductory book or tutorial.

Comment: `SELECT a.pname, b.testrunid FROM products as A LEFT JOIN tests as B on a.pname = b.pname where b.testresulty = 'PASS' and b.time >= '2017-10-11' and group by a.pname`

Answer (score 3):

Use conditional aggregation. The `COUNT` function count `NULL` values as zeros automatically, therefore, there is no need to take care of that.

```
select p.pname,
       count(case when testresult = 'PASS' then 1 end) as total_pass,
       count(case when testresult = 'FAIL' then 1 end) as total_fail,
       count(case when testresult = 'PASS' and time >= curdate() - INTERVAL 6 DAY then 1 end) as pass_lastweek  ,
       count(case when testresult = 'FAIL' and time >= curdate() - INTERVAL 6 DAY then 1 end) as fail_lastweek  ,
from products p
left join tests t on t.pname = p.pname
group p.id, p.pname
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you need to `LEFT JOIN` the first table with the second one before you group. The join will give you a row for each product (even if there are no test results to join it to; `INNER JOIN` would exclude products with no associated tests) + an additional row for each test result (beyond the first). Then you can group them.

```
SELECT products.*, tests.* FROM products 
LEFT JOIN tests ON products.pname = tests.pname 
GROUP BY products.id
```

Also, I would *strongly* recommend using a `product_id` column in the tests table, rather than using `pname` (if a products.pname changes, your whole DB breaks unless you also update the pname field in kind for every test result). The general query would then look like this:

```
SELECT products.*, tests.* FROM products 
LEFT JOIN tests ON products.id = tests.product_id
GROUP BY products.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I used 2 queries , the first with **conditional count** and the second one is to change all **null** values into 0 :

```
select pname, 
    case when total_pass is null then 0 else total_pass end as total_pass,
     case when total_fail is null then 0 else total_fail end as total_fail,
      case when pass_lastweek is null then 0 else pass_lastweek end as pass_lastweek,
       case when fail_lastweek is null then 0 else fail_lastweek end asfail_lastweek from (
    select products.pname,
           count(case when testresult = 'PASS' then 1 end) as total_pass,
           count(case when testresult = 'FAIL' then 1 end) as total_fail,
           count(case when testresult = 'PASS' and time >= current_date -7 DAY then 1 end) as pass_lastweek  ,
           count(case when testresult = 'FAIL' and time >= current_date -7 DAY then 1 end) as fail_lastweek  ,
    from products 
    left join tests  on tests.pname = products.pname
    group 1 ) t1
```